# How to output SQLite database in a different project in EF Core 3

Tags: sqlite, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, .net-core-3.1

I have a solution with 2 projects

```
src
|-ProjectA
|-ProjectB
```

ProjectA is a class library targeting netstandard2.1, it contains the DbContext (with `"Data Source=blog.db"`), the entities and it has a dependency on `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite`

ProjectB targets a netcoreapp3.1 and has a dependency on `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`. I just use it to manage migrations because migrations need a framework.

The SQLite database does not exist, so I create the first migration with dotnet tools from the ProjectB

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --project ../ProjectA
```

and it successfully creates the Migrations folder with the initial one.

Now I want to update the db so that the SQLite *.db is actually created.
If I do this:

```
dotnet ef database update --project ../ProjectA
```

the *.db file is created but in the ProjectB. I want the file to be output in the ProjectA but I cannot find a way to do so.

The doc does not seem to mention anything and neither the `ef database update --help`

---

**UPDATE 1**: I have tried to create and update migrations from the ProjectA instead and point to the executable project like this:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --startup-project ../ProjectB
```

and it creates properly the Migrations in ProjectA. Now I try to apply them to generate the *.db like this:

```
dotnet ef database update --startup-project ../ProjectB
```

and it generates the *.db file... but again in ProjectB! not in ProjectA where I want.

It seems wherever the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` package is, the generated database is placed there.

---

**UPDATE 2**: Specifying the project when updating database to point to where the DbContext is, didn't work either. It keeps generating the *.db in Project B

```
dotnet ef database update --startup-project ../Sasw.SimpleBlog.Storage.SQLite.Migrator/ --project ./
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by specifying a full path at my connection string. It's sufficient because this path should be configurable in settings.

```
public class DatabaseContext
    : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Thing> Things{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.UseSqlite("Data Source=D:\\database.db");
    }
}
```

The only problem left here is how to pass this connection string at runtime by using the `dotnet ef` CLI. But that seems an open question atm https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10750

Answer (score 0):

I know its kinda late for this response but maybe this helps, i haven't tried it.
Have you tried choosing a different default project in Visual Studio's Package Manager Console?

[image: Package Manager Console - Default Project select]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26621527)

Comment: Thanks @Akshay, i didnt knew that the images could also be embedded directly, just took the image button from the editor :) also thanks to piraces who edited :)